# Generate all Months between two dates column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, apply

I am trying to generate all months between two dates columns. I have the following dataframe:

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 01-15-2010 | 08-15-2010 |
| 07-01-2009 | 01-13-2010 |

My desired out put would be adding a month column that includes all months available between StartDate and EndDate columns.

Output:

| StartDate | EndDate | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-15-2010 | 08-15-2010 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 |
| 07-01-2009 | 01-13-2010 | 7,8,9,10,11,12,1 |

I tried writing this code but it's not working as I wanted.

```
date_range= lambda x:range (x['StartDate'].month,x['EndDate'].month+1)
df=df.assign(month=df.apply(date_range, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using *dateutil.rrule*

**Code:**

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
def month_between_dates(start_date, end_date):
    months_between = [str(dt.month) for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, 
                                dtstart = start_date.replace(day=1), 
                                until = end_date.replace(day=1))]
    return ",".join(months_between)
in_df["Month"] = in_df.apply(lambda x: month_between_dates(x["StartDate"],
                                                           x["EndDate"]), axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
StartDate    EndDate            Month
2010-01-15 2010-08-15  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2009-07-01 2010-01-15 7,8,9,10,11,12,1
```

**Code explanation:**

```
months_between = [str(dt.month) for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, 
                            dtstart = start_date.replace(day=1), 
                            until = end_date.replace(day=1))]
```

**start_date.replace(day=1)** converting date to first day.

**for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart = start_date,until = end_date)** iterating over the months between starting and ending dates.

Answer (score 0):

Create months periods with datetimes by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then create [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) per zipped `Series` with extract months:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate']).dt.to_period('m')
e = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate']).dt.to_period('m')

df=df.assign(month=[pd.period_range(y, x).month.tolist() for x, y in zip(e, s)])

print (df)
    StartDate     EndDate                     month
0  01-15-2010  08-15-2010  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
1  07-01-2009  01-13-2010  [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1]
```

If need strings joined by `,` use:

```
df=df.assign(month=[','.join(pd.period_range(y, x).month.astype(str)) 
                    for x, y in zip(e, s)])

print (df)
    StartDate     EndDate             month
0  01-15-2010  08-15-2010   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1  07-01-2009  01-13-2010  7,8,9,10,11,12,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectored solution based using only [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html?highlight=date_range#pandas.date_range) and [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

input_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'StartDate': ['01-15-2010', '07-01-2009'],
        'EndDate': ['08-15-2010', '01-13-2010']
    }
)
input_df = input_df.apply(pd.to_datetime)


def create_months_between(from_timestmp: pd.Timestamp, to_timestamp: pd.Timestamp, return_string=False) -> str:
    """returns a list of months between dates

    Args:
        from_timestmp (pd.Timestamp): datetime from
        to_timestamp (pd.Timestamp): datetime to
        return_string (bool, optional): Retrun a string of months, not a list. Defaults to False.

    Returns:
        str: list of ints if return_string==False, string of values if return_string==True
    """

    list_result = [value.month
                   for value
                   in pd.date_range(
                       from_timestmp,
                       to_timestamp,
                       freq='M',
                       normalize=True
                   )
                   ]
    list_result.append(np.datetime64(to_timestamp).astype(
        'datetime64[M]').astype(int) % 12 + 1)

    result_string = ','.join([str(value) for value in list_result])
    return result_string


input_df.columns
input_df['Month'] = np.vectorize(create_months_between)(
    input_df['StartDate'], input_df['EndDate'])
input_df
```

It returns a table, that looks like the one you described.

| StartDate | EndDate | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-15 | 2010-08-15 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 |
| 2009-07-01 | 2010-01-13 | 7,8,9,10,11,12,1 |